# error using variable as field of class (Object doesn't support this property or method)

Tags: vb.net

I get an error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method) on the following If evaluation.

I've already tried "For Each prtr As String" and "For Each prtr As Object"

If if I code "If doav(i).d1" or "If doav(i).d42", etc it goes well...

d1, d42, etc are boolean fields

```
Dim ports As Object = {"d1", "d42", "d123", "d1027", "d1089", "d2109", "lei", "d4130"}
  For Each prtr As String In ports
      For i As Integer = 0 To A - 1
         If doav(i).prtr = True Then   
             do something
         End If
      Next
  Next
```

Comment: A is a variable passed from another function ranging betwen 1 and 4

Comment: what is `doav`? show the declaration etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe the array declaration is the problem. You are not instructing **ports** to be an array, just saying is a single *Object*.

```
Dim ports() As Object = New Object(7) {"d1", "d42", "d123", "d1027", "d1089", "d2109", "lei", "d4130"}
```

I hope this works. Please let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

1- Turn option strict on
2- Code a little bit at a time and debug it properly. (for example: test your first loop before doing something else).

You should be initializing a string array, not just an object

```
    Dim ports As String() = {"d1", "d42", "d123", "d1027", "d1089", "d2109", "lei", "d4130"}

    For Each prtr As String In ports

    Next
```